# replace a word in a text file with the entire content of another file - sed

Tags: sed

I regularly use sed to replace words in text files with a variable or another word but what I would like to do is replace a place holder with the content of another file.

In essence merging two documents together at a specific point in the target file.

It would be easy if i just had to append the text to the bottom of the file but the text I wish to insert is right in the middle.

Comment: Consult `man sed` and read about the `r` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it

```
sed -i -e '/text/ r 2.txt' 1.txt
```

Comment: Please [format your code properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777). Nothing wrong with using `-e`, but it's not needed if you're only passing a single script (a single string containing `sed` commands). The `-i` syntax _without an option-argument_ is specific to _GNU_ `sed`.

Comment: You are inserting the contents of  2.txt into 1.txt _after_ the line containig `text`, but you are not replacing the placeholder, as you yourself had requested...